# What are typical problems that would require TPL library?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm currently reading *Pro. NET 4.0 Parallel Programming in C#*, however there are no exercises at the end of each chapter. Though I understand the concept, I still feel lacking some actual practices. I need some real problems to reinforce what I learned. I searched over the internet, but mostly tutorials...
Are there problem sets that target only on TPL? I found this library fascinating in many ways and I just want to ace it. So I wonder if someone could share me some problems in the domain of TPL so that I can practice my knowledge. Any problem or reference that you have encountered would be greatly appreciated. I just need problems, I will find the solution myself. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TPL is all about scalability in my opinion. If think about it this way, you'll find ways to utilize it in your code. If it’s not done in parallel - it’s done sequentially. In a small application with very little action - sequential processing is great. But when you have thousands of requests for a specific process - this is where TPL would come in.

Say you want to process a list of requests. In the requests is a url to a website. The process is to download the HTML content and pull specific data from the page and store it in a database. Normally this would have to be done sequentially. Now imagine 10 people perform this requests simultaneously. The person who press the submit button last will have to wait until all others before him have finished processing. This can take a very long time and increments indefinitely.

Visual Representation:

```
[Request01] - Finished 
[Request02] - Started
[Request03] - Waiting
[Request04] - Waiting
[Request05] - Waiting
[Request06] - Waiting
[Request07] - Waiting
[Request08] - Waiting
[Request09] - Waiting
[Request10] - Waiting
```

With TPL - You can store these request in a Concurrent Collection (TPL Collections) and iterate over the collection in Parallel. TPL not only splits these request up in threads and runs them simultaneously, it does so on each core on the processor(s).

Say you have a server with two dual core processor; the process would look something like this:

```
CPU1 Core1
  [Request01] - Finished 
  [Request02] - Started
  [Request03] - Started

CPU1 Core2
  [Request04] - Finished 
  [Request05] - Started
  [Request06] - Started

CPU2 Core1
  [Request07] - Finished 
  [Request08] - Started
  [Request09] - Started

CPU2 Core2
  [Request10] - Finished
```

As you can see - this allows for greater production and less wait time. The good thing about TPL - if you can develop a sound application the scalability will be dropped off the software’s back onto the hardware- which is great. The bigger you audience becomes to this service, the more servers you throw in the mix. In the IT world - this is more acceptable. Everyone is willing to scale-up their hardware; no one wants to update their software.

I hope this helps point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there are special problem sets which can be solved only with TPL.

> The purpose of the TPL is to make developers more productive by simplifying the process of adding parallelism and concurrency to applications. The TPL scales the degree of concurrency dynamically to most efficiently use all the processors that are available.  By using TPL, you can maximize the performance of your code while focusing on the work that your program is designed to accomplish

This is the description / purpose of TPL from msdn, and i think it sums it up nicely; 

I think that what you're asking about tpl can generally be asked about multi threading, and im not sure its always easy to tell whether multi threading is the best solution performance wise, or not (except for very obvious cases, when your code needs to access independent data source, or something like that). Event when you decide multi threading is the best solution for your problem, theres no automatic way to tell how many threads to use and how to divide the work between them.

Lets say you have an application that has to send X emails through some web service. Would you send all the X in one big loop? would you divide them into separate N threads and send X/N in each thread? Those questions can sometimes only be answered  with trial and performance profling monitoring, and as far as i can tell, the TPL library aims to solve this for you: instead of expecting from you to do all those calculcations (which also might not get you the same result on each execution), the tpl aims to count the required level of parallelism for you dynamicly, and thus, theoretically at least, proivde the best performance in each case.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked several times with TPL and find it very helpful. From my experience, I had the following challenges:

1. I was working on an online payment system. Theoretically, there could be from hundreds to thousands of payments per second. For each payment, I had to call a web service to notify service provider that someone paid n amount of money. Because calling a service is an IO operation, it was out of question to call the service from the site itself, because we would run out of threads from the pool very shortly. That's why I decided to use a job scheduler. The job runs periodically and fetches pending payments (transactions) from database and that's where TPL shines. Sending hundreds or thousands calls to service one by one is very inneficient.  That's why I used TPL. It allocates optimal amount of threads automatically and calls appropriate services in parallel. As I said, because web service call is an IO operation, it was ok (and probably a mandatory) to allocate more threads than logical cores on the machine.
2. Another problem is, when you need to process a large amount of data (which could be represented as an array of collection for example) where IO operation doesn't happen, everything is CPU bound. You can use TPL to distribute load across several cpus/cores. In this situation, it is best to have 1 thread per cpu core.